# Docky 2.1.2 crashes when I try to remove a existing dock

Tags: docky

I believe it has something to do with the Mounter Applet. The dock I'm trying to remove has 2 instances running for reasons I don't know. It also crashes when I try to remove Mounter.

How can I remove Docky completely including all my settings? I tried it from the Software Center and re-installed it but the dock I'm trying to remove still was there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd recommend you to launch docky through the terminal.
Type:

```
killall docky && docky
```

Then, try to recreate the problem. See what's appears on the terminal window.

If you want to reset the docky settings, probably typing

```
$ sudo apt-get purge docky
$ rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/docky*
$ sudo apt-get install docky
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Also, you should see if a similar bug is already on Launchpad. If not, then file a new one and post your terminal output there.